# What do latching operation mean?

Tags: microprocessor

While dealing with my notes on 8255A operation mode (Interfacing) in Mode 0. I came across the statement **'Each port can be programmed in either input mode or output mode where outputs are latched and inputs are not latched.'** Which seems confusing. 
What do  **latching mean,**  in general language if i were to teach non technical person. Microprocessor: 8255A

Comment: Do you know what a latch is in electronic terms?

Comment: I think it's something like grabbing the data. Pretty unsure about that. Please enlighten.

Comment: Enlightenment = google

Comment: Latching here means capturing the value. Latch is typically used to describe a transparent latch circuit, flip-flop to describe an edge-triggered circuit. That's the case with your 8255, which derives timing and operation from the CPU's bus control signals and its port signals, rather than referencing things to a free-running (bus) clock input pin. You'll find more on these terms on the interweb.

Comment: Latch is exactly what it sounds like... _To lock something in place._ So a latch for a circuit means it's locking the output in place from the input. This is the very foundation of digital memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In (digital) electronics **latching** means that the signal "locked" in a certain state (zero or one) unless a clock or other control signal **allows it to change**.

So for the 8255A the inputs are not latched, this means that the chip will respond **immediately** (I'm ignoring the effect of delays which are always present) to any change at the inputs.

The 8255A's outputs are latched so that means they will only change when a certain control signal "says so". Look at the datasheet of the [8255A](http://aturing.umcs.maine.edu/~meadow/courses/cos335/Intel8255A.pdf) on the first page there's this drawing:

[image]

Note how there's a signal from the "Read Write Control Logic" (bottom left)
going to all the Group ports on the right. I bet that that is the latching signal for the outputs.

In general it is convenient to have signals in digital logic **only change** at the transitions of the clock. Any signal which does not meet this requirement already can be **latched** (with the clock) and then it will meet this requirement.

Comment: Thank you @Bimpelrekkie for giving small time to share small knowledge. :) Appreciate small help.

Comment: Is hold circuit a type of latch?

Comment: @SuryaBhusal *Is hold circuit a type of latch?* That depends on what you mean by a "hold circuit". For example a sample-and-hold circuit is an analog circuit and definitely not a latch. In digital a "latch" is a common name for a certain function. The circuit itself may vary though (CMOS, TTL etc). I would not know what function a "hold" would describe. Brobably most people in the field would say its a latch.